# Calling void function more than once stops execution

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    char *str1;
    char *str2="HelloW";
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);
    to_lower_case(str1);
    to_lower_case(str2);
    printf("The string in lower case is %s\n", str1);
    printf("2nd string in lower case is %s",str2);
    return 0;
}

void to_lower_case(char *str) {
    while (*str != '\0') {
        if (*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z')
            *str += 32;
        str++;
    }
}
```

to_lower_case() is used to convert a string into lower case, but if I use this function more than once the program just takes input and then stops execution giving no output.

Expected that it would convert the strings passed to it into lower case, whenever to_lower_case() function is called.

> Input: SpiderMan
> Output: spiderman

Comment: `str2` is a string literal and your `to_lower_case` is attempting to modify it, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: `str1` has no space allocated to it, and reading string into it is causing UB as well.

Comment: `str1` has not been initialized, and points off into the giggleweeds.  Undefined behavior (aka hijinks & hilarity) ensue.

Comment: Which language is this, C or C++? Those are two different languages. Note that `char *str2="HelloW";` isn't valid C++, so this is either C or you're using compiler extensions.

Comment: Side note: C gives no guarantees that all capital letters can be found between `'A'` and `'Z'` or that adding 32 to the character will convert the character to lower case. Use [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) and [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) instead. Or just `tolower` because if there's no conversion to be done, nothing happens.

Comment: @Soumik Seal  Also remove the trailing 's' in the format string in the call of scanf scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);

Comment: @user4581301 And the `is*()` and `to*()` functions declared in `<ctype.h>` have undefined behavior on negative arguments other than `EOF`. If you want to apply them to a `char` argument, cast the argument to `unsigned char`.

Comment: As @user4581301 suggests, use `tolower()`. But, drop the `isupper()`. Characters passed to `tolower()` do not need to be pre-screened. Digits or punctuation, for instance, will be unaffected...

Comment: @user4581301 just a thought... Isn't it time to bury EBCDIC alongside the vacuum tube era computers it used to run on? :-) Most modern s/390 use ASCII, I believe

Comment: It would have been easier if the crash happened on the first call.

Comment: @CraigEstey past time. C++ finally admitted that two's compliment is the law of the land, so yeah, it's probably coming up on time to respect the dominance of ASCII.

Comment: @CraigEstey even C23 still does not recognise ASCII as a standard: there are always nit-pickers who say "but what if they are using EBCDIC" and its peculiar, disjointed sequence of the alphabet.

Comment: @WeatherVane ... or "wide characters" in beginner assignments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);`

   - `str1` is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value, so you don't know where it points. Writing the result of the scan therefore has undefined behavior. Furthermore, even if you made `str` point at a properly allocated buffer, the `scanf` should be made to not scan for more characters that would fit in that buffer or else a user's input could make `scanf` write out of bounds - again with undefined behavior as a result.
   - `s` doesn't belong to `%[` and will try to match whatever input the user provides. Remove that.
   - Always check the return value from `scanf` so that you know if it succeeded or not.
2. `to_lower_case(str2);`

   - `str2` points at a string literal. String literals, although not being made up of `const char`s should be seen as-if they were. Under many circumstances they are placed in read-only memory and trying to change them makes the program have undefined behavior.

An example without those issues:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void to_lower_case(char *str) {
    for (; *str != '\0'; ++str) {
        *str = tolower((unsigned char)*str);
    }
}

int main() {
    char str1[1024];        // a mutable character array
    char str2[] = "HelloW"; // another mutable character array

    puts("Enter a sentence:");

    // do not let it read more than the buffer size -1
    // to leave room for the terminator, '\0' and check the
    // return value from scanf:
    if (scanf("%1023[^\n]", str1) == 1) {
        to_lower_case(str1);

        printf("The string in lower case is %s\n", str1);
    } else {
        fputs("input failed\n", stderr);
    }

    to_lower_case(str2);
    printf("2nd string in lower case is %s", str2);
}
```

An even better option would be to use `fgets`:

```c
    if (fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin)) {
        to_lower_case(str1);

        printf("The string in lower case is %s\n", str1);
    } else {
        fputs("input failed\n", stderr);
    }
```

Comment: As noted in comments, the trailing `s` in the format string will probably also cause problems. The return value of `scanf` should always be checked.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I added some notes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for this detailed explanation 